# Execute a calculation on each incoming data record in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am consuming a kafka topic and I want to execute a calculation when a new data record is incoming. The calculation should be done on data of the incoming record and the two previous ones (like shown in the picture saved as a link here). Is it possible to somehow buffer the last two records so that I can operate with these and the new record?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otcsj.png)

Comment: "Is it possible to somehow buffer the last two records so that I can operate with these and the new record?" -> Yes, it is possible. Have a look at windowing and stateful KafkaStreams applications.

Comment: Sure, on Stackoverflow it is best to come up with a concrete coding issue. Try to avoid questions that can be answered with yes or no. Feel free to try something out and in case you are blocked or getting an exception come back here and describe what you have done and provide details (error logs) why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by mike, this is a very broad question. From what you wrote, this looks like something you could do quite well with Kafka Streams. You might want to have a look at [this intro](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this simply by using KSql. KSQL is a SQL streaming engine for Apache Kafka. It provides an easy-to-use interactive SQL like interface for stream processing on Kafka, without the need to write code in a programming language like Java or Python.
Kindly find the tutorial https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksqldb/tutorials/index.html